# How to plot different time data in x-axis in grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have two release data in different time intervals. But I want to plot these two releases in the  grafana with same interval time. can this possible to fake the time interval and plot the graph? . Because x-axis default it takes time-series. So i can't go with other parameters.

Please suggest on this.

Comment: Which time series database are you using? Influx? Graphite? Something else?

Comment: I am using influx .searched in many links, grafana 4.0 support non time series in x-axis (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/5917)  . But i installed 4.1 even i didn't choose x-axis as non time series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the X-Axis Mode option on the Graph panel?

[image: X-Axis Mode Option]

Comment: No i want CPU metrics for two different time-series should plot on same panel. Example release one cpu metrics (6 months back) with release 2 cpu metrics (current time) should plot on same panel

Comment: Aha, you want to know how to time shift your query. There is a panel timeshift override in Grafana: http://docs.grafana.org/reference/timerange/#panel-time-overrides-timeshift. It's not exactly what you want but you could have two panels on the same dashboard, one for current time and one for 6 months ago. I will check if InfluxDB has a timeshift function so that you can do it per query instead.

Comment: Hey many thanks . that what i want , I know that panel time shift override. But i am looking for on one pannel?.

Comment: Not sure that you can in InfluxDB. There are timeshift/offset functions in Graphite and Prometheus but I can't find any in the InfluxDB docs. It looks like they are on the Influxdb roadmap - https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5930 There are two issues there for lag and lead variables. Sorry, maybe someone else has a better idea on how to do this with InfluxDB.

Answer (score 2):

I've created graphs like this, although it took a bit of work.

To start out, InfluxDB doesn't support timeShift yet as detailed here:

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/142

So I used a separate HTTP server called the influxdb-timeshift proxy:

https://github.com/maxsivanov/influxdb-timeshift-proxy

My stack looked like this:

```
Grafana Dashboard --> influxdb-timeshift-proxy --> InfluxDB
```

Here are descriptions of the two "-->" in the above schematic:

- The --> on the left:  I created a Grafana Datasource to point to the
  tcp port of the influxdb-timeshift-proxy
- The --> on the right: The "influxdb-timeshift-proxy" startup
  configuration points to the InfluxDB server.

With this in place, to get the time shifting to happen, the SQL-like statements to InfluxDB need a carefully formatted field 'alias' like this:

```
"SELECT mean( "meanAT" ) AS shift_855296_seconds" blah blah sql blah.
```

See the influxdb-timeshift-proxy github page above for syntax details.

With a Grafana dashboard, to get two lines (aka series) on a time series graph, I configure two sql statements.  The above represents one SQL from a test 9-10 days ago, then I'd SELECT a different test (my baseline that I ran today) with timeshift of 0:

```
"SELECT mean( "meanAT" ) AS shift_0_seconds" blah blah sql blah.
```

So that answers your question, but it is of limited use -- because some poor human has gotta calculate the difference between the test times then dial the result (shift_855296_seconds) into the SQL in the Dashboard.

Why?  because out-of-the-box, Grafana Dashboards execute SQL statements that are (mostly) hard-configured into a dashboard.

To get Grafana to execute SQL where the shift alias is dynamically generated, I 
wrote a Grafana Scripted dashboard in javascript.  Here are the high-level instructions for scripted dashboards:

http://docs.grafana.org/reference/scripting/

FYI, Grafana scripted dashboards are poorly documented and the 'development environment' for debugging is primitive, at best, and I was unable to get the javascript 'require' thingy (that includes 3rd party libraries) to work.  But there is limited help on the Grafana discussion board and it does actually work -- creating a very nice time shifting dashboard on the fly is possible.

The http URLs to launch/display the 'scripted dashboard' can easily be embedded in some other dashboard you create.  Just add your scripted dashboard URL to a "Text Panel" using markdown:

http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/text/

Ultimately, the influxdb-timeshift-proxy is a stop-gap solution.
I have not tried it, but it looks like Kapacitor can also be used to provide the timeshifting, as described here:

https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.3/nodes/shift_node/

--Erik

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. 
If you want to just mark your release - you can use Annotations - http://docs.grafana.org/reference/annotations/#influxdb-annotations.

If you want to show dashboard only for specific timeframe - you can encode that in URL with 'from' and 'to' parameters - https://[your-dashboard-url]?from=1488868669245&to=1488873058626
But yes, there's no way how you can put a parameter on X-axis in current Grafana.